# Where should I ask a question on how to turn a classifier decision tree into a regressor?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Question I would like to ask:

> I have code for a classifier decision tree, using cross-entropy. It chooses the label based on the most common predicted label. I would like to transform this into a regressor decision tree. I have read that this involves using MSE, but I can't figure out if I need to build an entirely new tree, or merely adapt this one in a few steps. Any guidance? I can provide my code if that would help.

I understand that Stack Overflow is not the place for this question. Where is a good site to ask?